# How to install cooja simulator in windows 7

Tags: networking, cooja

Is it possible to install cooja simulator in windows, but without virtual machine. I know that we can easily install that using virtual machine, but i want a method other than that.

Answer (score 0):

## COOJA_WINDOWS

COPY from ORIGINAL and ALL CREDITS TO : https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki for LINUX

After tiring efforts to install this I tried to get it on windows successfully!! DO STAR IT!!

[image]

[image]

`git clone https://github.com/gptshubham595/COOJA_WINDOWS`

install git bash tick add functions to cmd

`install choco` : https://chocolatey.org/docs/installation

`choco install ant`

set ANT_HOME, JAVA_HOME, COPY Tools.jar from jdk\lib to jre\ext

set JAVA_HOME as [image]

set in path variable as [image]

`contiki-ng/tools/cooja: ant run`